# How to connect two applications runninig within Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have an application running on my own server with `kubernetes`. This application is supposed to work as a gateway and has a `LoadBalancer` service, which is exposing it to "the world". Now I'd like to connect this application with other applications running within the very same `kubernetes cluster`, so they can exchange `HTTP requests` with each other.

So let's say that my Gateway app is running on the port `9000`, the app which I'd like to call runs on `9001`. When I make `curl my_cluster_ip:9001` it gives me a response. Nevertheless I never know, what the `Cluster IP` will be, so I can't implement this to my gateway app.

Use case is typing to the web browser `url_of_my_server:9000` -> this will call the gateway -> it sends `HTTP Request` to the other app running in the cluster on the port `9001` -> response back to the gateway -> response back to the user.

Where the magic has to happen and how to easily make these two apps to talk with each other, while only one will be exposed to "the world" and the other one will be accessible only from within the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose your app on port 9001 as a service (lets say `myservice`). 
When you do that `myservice.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` will resolve to IP addres of your app. More Info on DNS here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

And then you can access your app within Kubernetes cluster as:
`http://myservice.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9001`

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options for internal service discovery:

1. You can use the cluster-internal DNS service to find the other application, as detailed in the answer by bits.
2. if both the proxy and the app runs in the same namespace, there are environment variables that expose the IP and ports. This may mean you have to restart the proxy if you remove/readd the other application, as the ports may change.
3. you can run both apps as two different containers in the same pod; this will ensure they get scheduled on the same host, which allows you to communicate on the same host.

Also note that support for your HTTP proxy setup already exist in Kubernetes; take a look at [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and [Ingress Controllers](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/).